# How to select vertices at behind in Orthograpic view?

Tags: vertices

I used to press B in wire frame and drag area, all vertices were selected in blender 2.7.
but it does not work in 2.9.
Is any solution for this?

as you can see in pics, i select vertices in front view with B, but not all vertices are selected..
[image]

Comment: That's strange, it should work. However, the one thing that gets me is that even in wireframe preview mode, you should still be able to see the grid lines through your model, however in your image, they seem "blocked". How did you enter wireframe mode?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I pressed Z and choose wire frame.

Comment: Is the *toggle X-ray* option disabled? If disabled, you can enable it by pressing *Alt Z*

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Oh! I Toggled toggle x ray button and i can see the grid line throught model, and the vertices are selected! Thank you!

Comment: @CoolCoder yes that made this problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you can't select vertices at back face, check toggle x ray button is disabled.